# trouble with search in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter

I'm new to angular and experiencing some difficulty implementing a 'live search' type of feature. I have my JSON set as a variable in a javascript file and I am able to display that in the html with no problem. I then have a 'list' radio box which changes the size of the display. This is functional as well. I run into trouble, however, when accessing the reverse filter option which is denoted with another radio button. The intended result is to filter the book titles in reverse by their name, ye nothing happens. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuz6ddu1jt58c9c/books.js?dl=0) is my JSON if you want to see the structure. And below is the code where I try to perform the filter reverse action:

```
  <div class="container result">
     <div ng-class="list ? 'col-md-6' : 'col-md-4'" class="books" ng-repeat="books in books | filter:search | orderBy:'books.doc.name':reverse"> <a href="https://address/{{books.doc.name}}" target="_blank">
      <img ng-class="list ? 'col-md-2' : 'col-md-12'" ng-src="{{books.doc.thumbnail_590_url}}" alt="Click to read {{books.doc.name}}" title="Click to read {{books.doc.name}}" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
      <h4 ng-class="list ? 'col-md-10' : 'col-md-12'">{{books.doc.name}}</h4> 
  </div>
```

and heres the js:

```
angular.module("myApp",["ngSanitize"])
.filter('replace', function () {
var pat = / /gi;
return function (text) {
    var clean = text.replace(pat, "-");
    var temp = clean.split("---");
    if (temp.length>1) {
      clean = temp[0];
    }
    return clean;
};
})
.controller("Example", function($scope, $interval) {
$scope.search = "orig";
$scope.books = books;
$scope.reverse = false;
$scope.list = false;
});
```

Comment: Do you have a boolean variable `reverse`? It's supposed to be a boolean https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: I do have a boolean var for reverse. sorry, heres the js: `angular.module("myApp",["ngSanitize"])
.filter('replace', function () {
    var pat = / /gi;
    return function (text) {
        var clean = text.replace(pat, "-");
        var temp = clean.split("---");
        if (temp.length>1) {
          clean = temp[0];
        }
        return clean;
    };
})
.controller("Example", function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.search = "orig";
  $scope.books = books;
  $scope.reverse = false;
  $scope.list = false;
}); `

Comment: Don't put code here, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Angular filter will not work on a json object, rather the data must be in the form of a json array. I removed the highest level enclosing curly brackets and replaced them with square brackets in addition to removing the numbers and colons like "1272:" that can be seen in the json file I posted. Taking these steps converted my data to a json array and allowed me to use the live search functionality.